# Why lattice change its shape

Tags: modifiers

I have made a curve shape with the lattice modifier. As soon as i click the apply button the curve shape turn flat. Any suggestion to fix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that seems to be the effect of subsurfing, because lattice is after subsurf. try swapping lattice and subsurf, it does the same. you can apply subsurf first, though and then apply lattice.

Comment: @m.ardito i tried that but also same. I have applied all the modifier then it work. But i think its not the right process